# Numpy import error

Tags: windows, python-3.x, numpy

Проинсталирован python 3.6 , Windows 8.1 x64, numpy-1.13.0-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl .

При импорте модуля выдает ошибку:

> ImportError:
>   Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
>   likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
>   If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
>   files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
>
> Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

Comment: Пробовали делать то, что советуется в тексте ошибки?

Comment: Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.13.0, а затем инсталляция не помогло

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас наблюдаются проблемы с последней версий Numpy. Установите более стабильную версию прописав в терминале:

```
pip install numpy == 1.19.3
```

Мне помогло, надеюсь и вам поможет. Удачи!